# Get all GraphicsDevices or GraphicsConfigurations on which a particular window is displayed

Tags: java, swing, multiple-monitors

If I have a Swing `Window` which is displayed across more than one monitor, how can I get either all the `GraphicsDevice`s or all the `GraphicsConfiguration`s on which it appears?

`window.getGraphicsConfiguration()` only gets me one screen (either the one holding the largest portion of the window, or the one where the top left corner of the window resides). My ultimate goal is to be able to determine whether the window extends off of any of the screens, or overlaps taskbars/docks/menubars on any of them. This is made trickier by the possibility that a window extends beyond a taskbar to an adjoining screen, in which case overlapping the taskbar wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Does [How do I determine which monitor a Swing mouse event occurs in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248386/how-do-i-determine-which-monitor-a-swing-mouse-event-occurs-in?rq=1) help? One of the answers shows how to get the bounds of each monitor.

Comment: @DavidPostill I guess I was expecting something more elegant, but checking the bounds of each monitor to see whether they intersect the windows bounds ought to work.